# Proof $\operatorname B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

I'm trying to proof the equality $\operatorname B(x,y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ when $x,y>0,$ without using calculus in many variables. I've investigated about the topic but all references make use of Fubini Theorem. Anyone knows a proof or reference using calculus in single variable?

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You could also check the proof on page 3of9 in the link below. https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/gammabeta.pdf

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace transforms?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$

Substitution now:

$$u:=\frac t{1-t}=\frac1{1-t}-1\implies du=\frac{dt}{(1-t)^2}$$

so we get

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{x-1}}{(u+1)^{x-1}}\frac1{(u+1)^{y-1}} (u+1)^2du=\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{x-1}}{(u+1)^{x+y}}du$$

Now, we have

$$\Gamma(x):=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\stackrel{nu=t\implies ndu=dt}=n^x\int_0^\infty u^{x-1}e^{-un}du$$

Now put $\;n=s+1\;,\;\;x=w+z\;$ , so that we have:

$$\frac1{(s+1)^{w+z}}=\frac1{\Gamma(w+z)}\int_0^\infty u^{w+z-1}e^{-(s+1)u}du$$

Well, now substitute all this mess in the new expression we got for the Beta function above...

Comment: Thanks for answering @Timbuc. The problem is the same. At the end of your proof, is necessary to use Fubini's Theorem to get the desire result, :)

Comment: +1 @Suiz346 You are asking to show that the product of a pair of integrals is equal to product of another pair of integrals. Of course one will need Fubini's theorem at some point.

Comment: @Suiz346 Oh, not at all. I think you missed the point: it is **the product of two one-variable integrals** , and you do not need to put them in one single double one using Fubini: just write  down what's the meaning of the integrals!

Comment: @Suiz34 Thanks for answering :). At the begin I thought the same but, I believe is and abuse of the languge using the same notation of beta function in gamma function , isn't it? Or Am I wrong?

Comment: @Suiz346 :That is called circular reasoning,